# How do I see the training splits for an AutoML Tables training job?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

When training, AutoML will create three data splits: training, validation, and test. How do I see these splits when training?

When doing custom code training, these splits will be materialized on GCS/BigQuery with URIs given by the environment variables: `AIP_TRAINING_DATA_URI`, `AIP_VALIDATION_DATA_URI`, and `AIP_TEST_DATA_URI`. Is there something similar for AutoML?

Answer (score 0):

We don't provide the training/validation set if you're using the managed AutoML training API. But you can optionally export the test set when you create the training job. There's a checkbox in the training workflow.

[image: export test set to BigQuery]

However, if you're using AutoML through the new [Tabular Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/tabular-workflows/overview), you will have access to the split training data as an intermediate training artifact.